# Testing a getter method fails

Tags: android, junit, mocking, mockito, powermock

the class i want to test is posted below in the code section. I am trying to test the "getSubscriberName" method.
the test I coded is posted below in the testing section. but at run time the test fails and I receiv ethe below posted errors

the dependancies i use in build.gradle are posted below

please let me know how to correct the error and why I am getting it

**code**

```
public class ListViewModel {

private String mSubscriberName = null;

public ListViewModel(String subscriberName) {
    mSubscriberName = subscriberName;
}

public String getSubscriberName() {
    return mSubscriberName;
}

public void setSubscriberName(String name) {
    mSubscriberName = name;
}
```

}

}

**testing**:

```
public class ListViewModelTest {

@Mock
private ListViewModel mListViewModel = null;
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    mListViewModel = new ListViewModel("");
}

@Test
public void getSubscriberName() {
    ListViewModel spyListViewModel = spy(mListViewModel);
    when(spyListViewModel.getSubscriberName()).thenReturn("YXZ");

    String expectedSubscriberName = spyListViewModel.getSubscriberName();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedSubscriberName, spyListViewModel.getSubscriberName());
}

}
```

**erroe**:

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockmaker.PowerMockMaker.isTypeMockable(Ljava/lang/Class;)Lorg/mockito/plugins/MockMaker$TypeMockability;

at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:29)
at org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:186)
at org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.confirm(MockSettingsImpl.java:180)
at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:62)
at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1729)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:33)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.MockAnnotationProcessor.process(MockAnnotationProcessor.java:16)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.createMockFor(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:38)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.IndependentAnnotationEngine.process(IndependentAnnotationEngine.java:62)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.processIndependentAnnotations(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:57)
at org.mockito.internal.configuration.InjectingAnnotationEngine.process(InjectingAnnotationEngine.java:41)
at org.mockito.MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(MockitoAnnotations.java:69)
at org.mockito.internal.junit.JUnitRule$1.evaluate(JUnitRule.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

**gradle.build**:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

// required if you want to use Mockito for unit tests
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:2.7.22'
// required if you want to use Mockito for Android tests
androidTestCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-android:2.7.22'

testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule-agent:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-rule:1.6.1'
testCompile 'org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:1.6.1'

compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.1.0'
compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1'
compile 'com.solidfire.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson-parent:2.8.1'
compile 'com.solidfire.code.gson:gson-parent:2.6.2'
compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:25.1.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
}
```

Comment: may be it is not relevant to your error, but you are testing a mock, not your class.

Comment: would you please clarify..what does testing a mock mean??

Comment: 1.  your `mListViewModel `is defined as a Mock by annotation. 2. you wrap your mock inside a spy 3. you define that your `getSubscriberName` function should return"YXZ" and then verify that it was `expectedSubscriberName`

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding spy because it makes actual calls and makes your test case smell more by calling all the dependent class methods, please find solution for your question below(still I used spy as per your code)

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ListViewModelTest {
@InjectMocks
private ListViewModel mListViewModel;
@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
   // mListViewModel = new ListViewModel("");
}

@Test
public void getSubscriberName() {
    ListViewModel spyListViewModel = spy(Mockito.mock(ListViewModel.class));
    when(spyListViewModel.getSubscriberName()).thenReturn("YXZ");
    when(mListViewModel.getSubscriberName()).thenReturn("YXZ");
    String expectedSubscriberName = spyListViewModel.getSubscriberName();
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedSubscriberName, mListViewModel.getSubscriberName());
}

}
```